# Makefile: Filter out strings containing a character

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to filter out strings that contain a particular character, but it doesn't work.  I guess `make` does not support multiple `%` patterns?

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    echo $(filter-out %g%, seven eight nine ten)
```

Gives:

```
$ make test
echo seven eight nine ten
seven eight nine ten
```

It doesn't filter out "eight"?  Actually what I want to do is filter out from a list of filenames those containing "$".  (In a Java context.)

Any hope, or do I have to use `$(shell)`?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any way of doing it in make itself.

Comment: As the documentation says, only the first `%` character is a wildcard -- subsequent `%` characters match literal % characters in whatever you are matching.  So your command filters out names that end in `g%`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Does the following function meet the purpose?

```
FILTER_OUT = $(foreach v,$(2),$(if $(findstring $(1),$(v)),,$(v)))
$(call FILTER_OUT,g, seven eight nine ten)
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  Have never used those functions before.

Comment: Make sure that the pattern does not have extra spaces: `, pat,` and `,pat,` are **way** different.

Answer (score 17):

I recently did something similar using two `wildcards` functions for excluding some files

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    echo $(filter-out $(wildcard *g*.c),$(wildcard *.c))
```

Comment: Doesn't `wildcard` just find files in your current directory, though? The other solution is a bit more robust, I think.

Comment: @keith-m the following will work with any directory. It also ensures the excluded file pattern applies only to the file name and not on the folder path itself.
```$(filter-out $(wildcard my/folder/*g*.c),$(wildcard my/folder/*.c))```

Comment: @RomainVIOLLETTE What I meant is that even with your snippet, the files must all be in the same folder. No?